# Java rock, paper, scissors program with file input

Tags: java, java-io

I'm having a problem with my line.charAt(0) and line.charAt(2). I keep getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at RockPaperScissors1.main(RockPaperScissors1.java:31)
```

I can't figure out why I am getting that. My file looks like this:

```
3
2
R P
S R
3
P P
R S
S R
1
P R
```

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RockPaperScissors1
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {    
      File file = new File("a.txt");
      Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);


      int cases = fin.nextInt();
      String line = fin.nextLine();
      int rounds = fin.nextInt();

      for(int i = 0; i<cases; i++)
      {
         int tie = 0;
         int p1win = 0;
         int p2win = 0;

         for(int j=0; j<rounds; j++)
         {
            char p1 = line.charAt(0);
            char p2 = line.charAt(2);

            if (p1 == p2)
               tie = tie + 1;


            else if (p1 == 'R')
            {
               if (p2 == 'S')
                  p1win = p1win + 1;

               else if (p2 == 'P')
                  p2win = p2win + 1;
            }

            else if (p1 == 'P')
            {
               if (p2 == 'S')
                  p2win = p2win + 1;

               else if (p2 == 'R')
                  p1win = p1win + 1;
            }

            else if (p1 == 'S')
            {
               if (p2 == 'P')
                  p1win = p1win + 1;

               else if (p2 == 'R')
                  p2win = p2win + 1;
            }

         }

         if(p1win > p2win)
            System.out.println("Player 1");
         else if(p2win > p1win)
            System.out.println("Player 2"); 
         else
            System.out.println("Tie!");     
      }
   }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give you the exact answer to your question, I'm going to explain how you can chase it yourself.

Firstly, the error message explains what the error is, and where it's happening:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

... meaning you're trying to access the first character of the string, but it doesn't have that many characters in it.

```
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at RockPaperScissors1.main(RockPaperScissors1.java:31)
```

... meaning it's happening at line 658 of String.java -- well, that's beyond your control; String.java is part of the standard Java library. But that's being called by your code - line 31 of RockPaperScissors1.java.

If you're running in an IDE, it's likely that you can click on the line number in the message, to jump to that line in the code.

So now you're one layer deep into what the problem is: at some point it tries to execute:

```
char p1 = line.charAt(0);
```

... but `line` has a value of `""` at that point.

You can step through the execution mentally, to try and work out why `line` might be an empty string -- and that is good practice.

But you can also learn a lot by running the code in a *debugger*. Again, if you're in an IDE, you're only a couple of clicks away from a debugger. Check your IDE's documentation. Alternatively `jdb` comes with the standard JDK, but is less intuitive to use.

Since you know your problem is with the assignment to `line`, set a breakpoint at the `int cases=....` line. Start the program in debug mode. It will pause when it reaches that point.

Click the 'step' button, and look at the value assigned to `cases`.

Click the 'step' button again, and look at the value assigned to `line`.

Keep going in this way. When it does what you expect: good. When it does something you didn't expect, think about why, perhaps read the Javadocs for the method you're calling, and try again.

From looking at your code, I can tell that once you've got past this issue with `line` being empty, you'll encounter a few more issues -- but using the debugger and your brain you'll be able to deal with them all.

Comment: Got it figured out! Debugger helped a lot, thank you!